# Writing into My Contacts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I have been trying to create contact in My Contacts folder, so it could be synced with my phone. I would't mind using groups, but their synchronization is broken on iPhone. Anyway, I am using this script:

```
function update() {
  var group = ContactsApp.findContactGroup('My Contacts');
  group.addContact(ContactsApp.createContact('Fido','McDog', 'fido@example.com'));
  var contact = ContactsApp.findByEmailAddress('fido@example.com');
  contact.setWorkPhone('123123123123');
}
```

If I use any other name for 'My Contacts', the script works perfectly. Otherwise I get error: TypeError: Cannot call method "addContact" of null. (line 3)

Is that some sort of limitation from Google?

Thanks.

Comment: 'My Contacts' is not a group... just like  'My Drive' is not a folder, it is the root.
It's probably inappropriate to use the word 'root'  in the contact context but it's the same idea. You can create a contact directly and get a contact object to add whatever you want to it.

Comment: Ok it makes sense. If I just create contact it goes to Others.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the Group My Contacts is actually called "System Group: My Contacts". Other system groups are similarly named so, to add to My Contacts rather than Other ...

```
function test() {
 var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");
 group.addContact(ContactsApp.createContact('Fido','McDog', 'fido@example.com'));
 var contact = ContactsApp.findByEmailAddress('fido@example.com');
 contact.setWorkPhone('123123123123');
 }
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I was using just var newContact = ContactsApp.createContact(fName, actualLastName, email); and the contacts used to (up to a few months back) synch to my phone. Finally, I've found in this post how to get them synching again. I thought it was an issue with my phone but alas just that the contacts needed to be added to "My Contacts". Now I'll know who's calling again and can stop punching numbers in to make calls and texts!